# Error when connecting to mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a junior university student testing mongodb with node.js, in my code I was trying to connect to mongodb using mongoose, but for some reason my mongoose is not able to connect with the database, I have check the following:

mongodb actually install, I install mongodb via brew and mongod and mongo works
mongoose is in my directory

below is my error, any help would be apreciated

```
Express server listening on port 3000

/path/1_mongodb/connect_to_mongo/app.js:17
    throw err;
          ^
Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
    at null.<anonymous>     (path/1_mongodb/connect_to_mongo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:636:74)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
at null.<anonymous> (/path/1_mongodb/connect_to_mongo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:139:15)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/path/1_mongodb/connect_to_mongo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:476:10)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at net.js:426:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

App.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/todo_development')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Task = new Schema({
  task: String
});

var Task = mongoose.model('Task', Task);

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler()); 
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port,       app.settings.env);
```

Edit: So I realize that when trying accessing mongodb using node.js you should run mongod first.

Comment: When you say "I install mongodb via brew and mongod and mongo works", do you mean you just installed them or you also started the mongo daemon? When you type ```mongo``` in the shell, do you connect to the mongo shell?

Comment: yes I can have the test store on database via command prompt > db.test.save( { a: 1 } )

Comment: Any chance your machine doesn't have `localhost` configured properly? try 127.0.0.1

Comment: I have being using 127.0.0.1:3000 for testing node modules, but currently 127.0.0.1 cannot be connected, which is reasonable? because I didn' set up any server?

Comment: mongodb when running listens at localhost:27017. If you have mongod running on your machine and you can confirm that it works with the mongo client `mongo dbname` then you should be able to connect to it. Other possibilities are that you added a username/password, which have to be specified http-auth style in the url

Comment: yes, so if I run mongod from terminal, I can access localhost:27017 and it will return: You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number, but when I try to access mongodb using app.js my program terminates as the connection throws an err

Comment: oh, I just realize that you should run mongod on one terminal, and node app.js on another, lol